# How to do arithmetic operation in .rewriteRule function?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is this possible to do arithmetic operation in .rewriteRule function?I want to rewrite my url.

From this

> /view.php?id=2

To

> /?p=6 (id*2+2)

Comment: That's beyond the scope of Apache's abilities and should probably be done within PHP. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to rewrite my old url to my new wordpress blog.I can't able to change id on wordpress.

Comment: And all your new IDs follow the pattern `(id*2+2)`? Really? (The general way is redirecting blog posts one by one explicitly, as the IDs will usually not match)

Comment: Just now i created a post one by one on wordpress.It followed this pattern 2,4,6,8... as id.I planned to do it via php.

Comment: It's likely to be easiest with PHP. Adding PHP code to `view.php` that does a `header("location....")` redirect to the new resource.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a rewrite map to call an external program, it's going to be a bit slower under heavy load though. The rewrite map can only be defined in the server's config or vhost config, *not in an htaccess file*. But it can be used in an htaccess file.

So you have a simple script that reads from stdin and does your math:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$| = 1; # Turn off I/O buffering
while (true) {
    print <STDIN> * 2 + 2;
}
```

Then declare the mapping:

```
RewriteMap math prg:/path/to/script.pl
```

Then use the mapping in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^view\.php$ /?p=${math:%1} [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect http://example.com/view.php?id=2 to http://example.com/?p=6 you would do this:

in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]*)
RewriteRule view.php calc.php?id=%1 [L]
```

And in calc.php:

```
<?php  
$base_url = 'http://example.com/?p=';
$id = $_GET['id'];
$new_id = $id * 2 + 2;

$url = $base_url.$new_id;

header("Location: $url"); 
exit();
```